# How to get the MSE of the node in the DecisionTreeRegressor of scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the generated decision tree regression model, there is an MSE attribute when using `graphviz` to view the tree structure. I need to obtain the MSE of each leaf node, and carry out subsequent operations according to the MSE. However, after reading the document, I can't find the method to provide for output MSE. Other attributes such as feature name, sample number, prediction value, etc. All have are corresponding methods:

[image: Tree structure]

With `help(sklearn.tree._tree.Tree)`, I can see that most of the attributes have some methods to output the value, but I don't see anything about MSE.

Help on class Tree in module sklearn.tree._tree
[image: Help on class Tree in module sklearn.tree._tree]

Comment: How can we reproduce such plots? Whatever I do to `DecisionTreeRegressor`, the plots always contain `entropy`; never `mse`.

Comment: Just found a way. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question. You need `tree_reg.tree_.impurity`.

### Short answer:

```
tree_reg = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

extracted_MSEs = tree_reg.tree_.impurity # The Hidden magic is HERE

for idx, MSE in enumerate(tree_reg.tree_.impurity):
    print("Node {} has MSE {}".format(idx,MSE))

Node 0 has MSE 86.873403833
Node 1 has MSE 40.3211827171
Node 2 has MSE 25.6934820064
Node 3 has MSE 19.0053469592
Node 4 has MSE 74.6839429717
Node 5 has MSE 38.3057346817
Node 6 has MSE 39.6709615385
```

### Long answer using the `boston` dataset with visual output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import ensemble, model_selection, metrics, datasets, tree
import graphviz

house_prices = datasets.load_boston()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
    pd.DataFrame(house_prices.data, columns=house_prices.feature_names),
    pd.Series(house_prices.target, name="med_price"),
    test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

tree_reg = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

extracted_MSEs = tree_reg.tree_.impurity # YOU NEED THIS 
print(extracted_MSEs)
#[86.87340383 40.32118272 25.69348201 19.00534696 74.68394297 38.30573468 39.67096154]

# Compare visually
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(tree_reg, out_file=None, feature_names=X_train.columns)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)

#this will create an boston.pdf file with the rule path
graph.render("boston")
```

Compare MSE values with visual Output:

[image]

Comment: How does this provide the MSE value per node?

Comment: I am exactly extracting the MSEs values. Why downvote ?

Comment: You weren't before you edited your answer. I have removed it now. Please be cognizant that you were downvoted when your answer did not answer the question.

Comment: I missed that the OP need the actual values. My answer addresses exactly this now. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot ，This is exactly what I want

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```